# Facebook share button dynamic url

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I would like to be able to share a dynamic page with a facebook button. 
The button is working for a static page but not for a dynamic page. My dynamic page is created in $profie_url.  How can I use it in the facebook code?

```
$mRow = $this->row;
$wRow = $mRow->getInfo();
<?php $profie_url =  $this->url(array("id" => $mRow->id, "url" =>
                $this->urlify($mRow->first_name)));
 ?>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_CA/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo $profie_url; ?>" data-layout="button" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="">Share</a></div>
```

Comment: can you please explain a little more? what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: the code for the share button is for a static page. I would like to be able to share a dynamic page. the dynamic url is defined in $profie_url

Comment: so is your URL changing while remaining on the same page?

Comment: The process: a user has to connect on the website, he has a profile and it's that profile that i would like to be able to share. I can't use the current page as it's a page that he is logged in. That is why i created $profie_url

Comment: try using jquery to change the URL dynamically.

Comment: I created the script below but seems to have a problem with it <script language="javascript">
    function fbshareCurrentPage()
    {window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="<?php echo $profie_url?>+"&t="+document.title, '', 
    'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');
    return false; }
</script>

Comment: What does the actual HTML output that produces look like? Does the browser console report any errors when you trigger that function?

Comment: I posted the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution:

```
$id= $mRow->id;
$fn = $mRow->first_name;

<script language="javascript">

var id= <?php echo json_encode($id); ?>;
var fn = <?php echo json_encode($fn); ?>;

  function fbshareCurrentPage()
  {window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=www.abc.com/"+id+"/"+fn+"&t="+document.title, '', 
'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');
   return false; }
</script>
```